# how to change the bg color of a range of bars in tradingview python / pine editor

Tags: pine-script

Hi im a super noob at python, as in I started last night.   I am trying to combine two indicators on trading view into one basically, and add a few tweaks.  this is the entire script:

```
   study("Bitcoin tops and bottoms indicator with pi cycles and aroon", shorttitle="BTC tops and bottoms", overlay=true)
// Set vars.  355/113 = Pi.  pi cycle period daily.  Aroon period weekly.  
len_ma_long = input(355, minval=1, title="Long Moving Average")
len_ma_short = input(113, minval=1, title="Short Moving Average")
resolution = input('D', type=input.string, title="Time interval")
aroon_res = input('W', type=input.string, title="Aroon interval")
length = input(52, minval=1, title="aroon period ")
is_show_ma = input(false, type=input.bool, title="Show Moving Averages ?")
is_show_aroon = input(false, type=input.bool, title="Show Aroon ?")
is_alert = input(true, type=input.bool, title="Send an alert on Pi Cycle Top?")
//aroon data
upper = security(syminfo.tickerid, aroon_res, 100 * (highestbars(high, length+1) + length)/length )
lower = security(syminfo.tickerid,aroon_res, 100 * (lowestbars(low, length+1) + length)/length)
//moving avg data
ma_long = security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, sma(close, len_ma_long)*2)
ma_short = security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, sma(close, len_ma_short))
//get crossovers
src = security(syminfo.tickerid, resolution, close)
PiCycleTop = crossunder(ma_long, ma_short) ? src + (src/100 * 10) : na
buys = crossover(upper, lower) ? src + (src/100 * 10) : na
sells = crossover(lower, upper) ? src + (src/100 * 10) : na
b_color = buys ? color.green : sells ? color.red : na
bgcolor(b_color)
//draw MA and Arron if set in settings
plot(is_show_ma?ma_long:na, color=color.green)
plot(is_show_ma?ma_short:na, color=color.red)
plot(is_show_aroon?upper:na, "Aroon Up", color=#00FF00 )
plot(is_show_aroon?lower:na, "Aroon Down", color=#FF0000)
//add triangles
plotshape(PiCycleTop, style=shape.triangledown,size=size.normal, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, location=location.absolute)
plotshape(buys, style=shape.triangleup,size=size.normal, text="End Bear Bottom", color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(sells, style=shape.flag,size=size.normal, text="Start Bear Bottom", color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, location=location.belowbar)
//alerts
alertcondition(condition=PiCycleTop, title="Pi Cycle", message="The Pi Cycle Top has been reached, historically Bitcoin tops within 3 days of reaching this ratio, More info : https://medium.com/@positivecrypto/the-golden-ratio-multiplier-c2567401e12a")
plot(close)
```

When added to a chart looks like this:
[image]

What i want to do, but can not, is highlight the  background of all candels inbetween the green flag and the green triangle.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.  will paste incase it helps someone in the future

```
b_color = buys ? color.green : sells ? color.red : upper > lower ?color.green: upper < lower ?color.red: na
```